# FileNotFoundError in Docker django project even though the file is present

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, text-files, file-not-found

I don't have any prior knowledge in docker. I had created a django project and it was working correctly. Then I dockerised the project. Now I an getting this file not found error even though the file is present at the address. It is a normal text file which the views.py file needs to access.

This is my docker file

```
FROM python

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
```

Comment: If you could share the Dockerfile you wrote, it will be easier to help.

Comment: I have added the files. Can you please check?